# How to recieve notification of incoming transaction in metamask mobile in real time

Tags: transactions, erc-20, metamask, ropsten, mobile-wallet

I have a erc-20 token in the ropsten testnet and i am using my metamask for admin my token, and i just want to recieve a notification via sms, to take screenshot, whatsapp or another way frendly user, when i recieve an incoming transaction in the metamask mobile app instantly whe the transaction is confirmed.